# Using charAt with number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, numbers

I want to set some index to my statement and check it's found or not i found this method charAt but it's work just with strings so how to handle these with numbers

```
if (mobileNumber) {
        let j = mobileNumber.charAt(2);
        let w = mobileNumber.charAt(0);
        alert("@", w, j)
        if (j === 9) { //Not work quz it's a number
          alert("FoundJ", j)
          return;
        } else if (w === 6) { //Not work quz it's a number
          alert("FoundW", w)
          return
        } else{
           alert("sorry, App does not work in your city right now")
           return
          }
```

---

### Update

now I handle the index but I have some issue with them here is my Statements
if I write the number and it contains 9 || 6 in the (2)index I see the alert when calling the function I don't know why?

```
 let j = mobileNumber.toString().charAt(2);
      if (mobileNumber.length <= 0) {
        this.setState(
          Object.assign(validations, {
            mobileNumberValid: "• Please, write your Mobile Number"
          })
        );
        return;
      } else if (mobileNumber.length < 10) {
        this.setState(
          Object.assign(validations, {
            mobileNumberValid:
              "• Your Mobile Number must be exactly 10 characters!"
          })
        );
        return;
      } else if (regNumber.test(mobileNumber) === false) {
        this.setState(
          Object.assign(validations, {
            mobileNumberValid: "• Please, Your mobile must be a number"
          })
        );
        return;
      }
      else if (j != 9 || j != 6) { // i think the issue with **OR** 
        alert("sorry not work in your city yet!")
        return;
      }
 else {
        this.setState(
          Object.assign(validations, {
            mobileNumberValid: ""
          })
        );
      }
```

Comment: `j === "9"` ? ...

Comment: Sorry, check again

Comment: either do j === '9' or parseInt(j, 10) === 9 same with w

Comment: sadly, I don't understand you very well

Answer (score 1):

First convert number to string using `toString()`, then use `charAt(index)`

```js
var mobileNumber = 98812345;
console.log(mobileNumber.toString().charAt(1));
```

Comment: can you check the Q again?

Answer (score 0):

Just convert them to strings before:

```
if (mobileNumber) {
   let j = mobileNumber.toString().charAt(2);
   let w = mobileNumber.toString().charAt(0);
}
```

And if you need them as numbers, just parse them back:

```
let jNumber = parseInt(j, 10);
```

Comment: can you check the Q again?

Answer (score 0):

=== performs exact comparison without casting type (as far as I know)

If you have a numeric expression, you can convert it into string, then use charAt() to do your comparison

```js
function findJW(mobileNumber) {
    console.log("Checking "+ mobileNumber)
    let str = mobileNumber.toString();
    let j = str.charAt(2);
    let w = str.charAt(0);
  
    if (j == '9') {
       console.log("FoundJ", j)
    } else if (w == '6') {
      console.log("FoundW", w)
    } else{
      console.log("sorry, App does not work in your city right now")
    }
}

findJW(12954678)
findJW(62354678)
findJW(11111111)
```